# Conflict between flexisym and polynom packages

Tags: incompatibility, polynom

After isolating the problem, an aberrant behavior shows up if flexisym and polynom packages are added in beamer. The execution process jams indefinitely without any sign of errors. The following minimal working example elucidates the issue.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,polynom}
\usepackage{flexisym}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{center}
    \polyset{vars=s}
    \polylongdiv{s^2+1}{s^2-3s+2}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another conflict of `flexisym`. Avoid it.

Comment: @egreg it sounds there is a list of conflicts with `flexisym`

Comment: For some odd reason `flexisym` makes `^` an ordinary (_i.e.,_ not a superscript) character, but `\polylongdiv` expects otherwise. Reverting the catcode of `^` seems to work: `\usepackage{flexisym}\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\^=7 }`. Not using `flexisym` as egreg suggested seems a better idea.

Comment: flexisym is really just designed to underpin breqn and both packages are highly experimental and _by design_ incompatible with most standard math layout macros. Are you sure you want to use flexisym?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik it is ordinary so it can be made math-active with mathcode"8000 and given more specific definition than just the built in superscript processing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `mathstyle` (loaded by `flexisym`) already makes `^` math-active, but it makes it catcode 12 as well, thus my suggestion to switch back the catcode. I don't know what impact that may have on the working of `flexisym`.

Comment: Also, this is unrelated to `beamer`. The simpler `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{polynom}
\begin{document}
\polylongdiv{x^2+1}{x^2-3x+2}
\end{document}` causes the same problem.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik the mathcode "8000 would have no effect if `^` had catcode 7, it only kicks in if tex would otherwise typeset the character (so look up its mathcode)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oops :-) That's new to me. Thanks and sorry about the noise

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not really. Just wanna know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `flexisym` package changes the category code of `^` and `_` to 12, in order to make them math active.

The problem is that `polynom` uses the characters `^` and `_` with their standard category code to do tests.

#### Best solution

Forget about `flexisym`

#### Working solution

Load `polynom` with the appropriate category code setup.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{flexisym}

\catcode`^=12 \catcode`_=12
\usepackage{polynom}
\catcode`^=7 \catcode`_=8

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{center}
    \polyset{vars=s}
    \polylongdiv{s^2+1}{s^2-3s+2}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. The thing that I don't understand why the execution process hangs?!

Comment: @CroCo The `polynom` package is looking for a standard `^`, but it find a different brand of it.

Comment: Is this a bug? It should at least show a warning.

Comment: @CroCo No, it's not a bug. It's flexisym's fault.

Comment: From programming perspective, it shows a bad design by the package's writer. It shouldn't go on and on without stopping the process. It was actually a shot in the dark for me to notice this.

Comment: @CroCo You're wrong, sorry. The `polynom` package is actually very well written. The `flexisym` package is auxiliary to `breqn` and it is well known that it breaks ***many*** other packages. Both are dubbed as experimental.

Comment: May be I am wrong but the reality is harsh. A hanging process is a serious issue, just saying.

Comment: @CroCo Try writing `\def\fi{whatever}` just before `\begin{document}` and see what happens. If a package (`flexisym`) changes decade old conventions, there's not much one can do.